# Test Soap Services with PHPUnit

Tags: php, web-services, soap, phpunit

I'm trying to write tests for a Web Service. I need to monitor whether the service is online and returning data that makes sense (correct domain, length, format, etc...).

Unfortunatelly, I was unable to test using PHPUnit. It fails whenever it reaches the soap call line.

I've searched the web and found that I should mock the service. But that wouldn't solve my problem. I need to test the service - not the client.

Is it possible to allow remote soap calls from phpunit?

```
public function testByEmployee() {
    $client = new SoapClient('services_int.xml');
    $client->methodCall();
    $this->assertTrue(true);
}
```

This test fails.

Comment: Did this `$this->assertTrue($client,is_a('SoapClient'));` fail after `new`? Did `$this->assertTrue(file_exists('services_int.xml');` fail?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458411/how-to-mock-test-a-web-service-in-phpunit-across-multiple-tests

Comment: @JOUM both tests succeeds.

Comment: Hope the link above give u some hints

Comment: Is services_int.xml a valid WSDL, and is the endpoint in the file correct?